# Find a Fixed String in Notepad++

Tags: regex, plugins, notepad++

I have a text file of 400 000 lines.
I have to find a fixed string of the form "AAA BBB CCC" and if it occurs, just take the cursor at the beginning of it.

If it does not exist, just display it on alert box.

I don't want to do Ctrl+F: then type the string and then reach there.
I want any shortcut or a plugin to take me at the beginning of the string which is fixed in all case.

One solution is I have to create my own notepad++ plugin. I am looking for any possibility with existing plugins or regular expressions.